# MySQL: LEFT JOIN and COUNT

Tags: mysql, left-join

i'm using this query to get all locations:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
locations
WHERE
cat='Bars'
ORDER BY
locationname
ASC
```

Now i want to show the amount of existing events beside the locationinfo from the table 'events' too.

```
Table 'locations': (all unique locations)
locationid|locationname|address|cat

Table 'events': (different eventid's but maybe multiple hits for locationid)
eventid|locationid|eventname|eventdate
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(e.eventid), l.locationid
FROM locations l
LEFT JOIN events e ON l.locationId = e.locationId
WHERE cat='Bars'
GROUP BY l.locationId
ORDER BY .locationname ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to understand the fundamental issue:  using `left join`.  The rest is just `group by` and the right use of `count()`:

```
SELECT l.*, COUNT(e.locationid)
FROM locations l LEFT JOIN
     events e
     ON l.locationid = e.locationid
WHERE l.cat = 'Bars'
GROUP BY l.id;
```